# is there a constant leakage current across axon even in absence of stimuli?

Tags: neuroscience

because of resting potential is their a constant leakage current across membrane due to resistance of membrane and ion pumps continuously pump restore the resting potential ?

Comment: yes - and now I have to fill up the minimal amount of characters

Comment: Have a look here  -  http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/36123/if-the-average-resting-potential-of-a-neuron-is-70-mv-why-is-there-such-a-high/36127#36127