# About cell membrane; action potential and resting potential

Tags: neuroscience, homework, action-potential

Ion X is negatively charged and more concentrated inside than outside the membrane potential of a cell
therefore Ex (equilibrium) is positive. Ion X is unknown.
Why is the equilibrium positive?

Comment: Assuming this is a homework assignment, we do expect OP to show prior research effort. At the very least you can provide the meaning of the acronyms used and a plausible way how you think the problem should be tackled. Good luck!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If the average resting potential of a neuron is -70 mV, why is there such a high ratio of potassium ions inside relative to out?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/36123/if-the-average-resting-potential-of-a-neuron-is-70-mv-why-is-there-such-a-high)

Comment: (note: the question isn't an exact duplicate, but otherwise it should be closed as a "homework" problem due to low effort; the principles addressed in the other question should help the OP, however)