# How's the membrane potential restored to resting state after hyper polarisation?

Tags: neurophysiology, biophysics, electrophysiology

I have known for so long that Na<sup>+</sup>/ K<sup>+</sup> pump restores the membrane potential. But as it pumps in 2 K<sup>+</sup> for every 3+ Na<sup>+</sup> moving out how can it make the membrane potential less negative when the net result is one positive charged ion moving out?

Comment: If you see a normal AP curve, you would be able to appreciate that the membrane potential is generally brought back - which is around -70mV. So the potential doesnt matter much since its restored by the ion fluxes. What matters most is the ion composition on either side. You might see that after depolarization, Na+ came in (it generally satys out) and after hyperpolarization K+ came in. The potential is safe but the distribution is altered. This is what the pump takes care of, not the potential (although slightly electrogenic)

Answer (score 6):

The Na,K-ATPase restores negative membrane potentials.  When a cell is hyperpolarized, [leaky K<sup>+</sup> channels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium_channel) take care of that. Leaky K<sup>+</sup> channels are always open. Generally, K<sup>+</sup> has the tendency to diffuse back out of the cell along its *[chemical gradient](https://physio1.wikispaces.com/Electrical+Gradient+vs.+Chemical+Gradient)* through leaky K<sup>+</sup> channels, after been pumped in, making the cell's inside more negative. However, in the reverse situation, where the cell is hyperpolarized, they may flow inwards, along the *[electrical gradient](https://physio1.wikispaces.com/Electrical+Gradient+vs.+Chemical+Gradient)*.

Note that while the Na,K-ATPase is indeed the driving force behind the membrane potential, it is not the direct consequence of the ratio of Na<sup>+</sup> being pumped out and K<sup>+</sup> being pumped into the cell. It is the leaky K<sup>+</sup> channels that determine the membrane potential largely, together with the Na<sup>+</sup> channels being permanently closed, except when an action potential is generated.

<sub>**Suggested further readings**

**-** [What keeps the resting potential of neurons constant at -70 mV?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/21394/what-keeps-the-resting-potential-of-neurons-constant-at-70-mv/36906#36906)

**-** [If the average resting potential of a neuron is -70 mV, why is there such a high ratio of potassium ions inside relative to out?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/36123/if-the-average-resting-potential-of-a-neuron-is-70-mv-why-is-there-such-a-high/36127#36127)</sub>